# Is it possible to pass variables between classes without using a navigator in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a 2 statefulwidgets that are supposed to do different jobs. One of them takes inputs from the user (using text fields) and adds them up then displays the result (I already got that figured out) and the next one is supposed to take these values from the first class and put them into a bar chart. I know how to put the data into a bar chart (I tried it with dummy values) but I don't exactly know how to pass those values from the first class to the second one without using a navigator. Using a navigator wouldn't work for me because I don't want to navigate between those two classes; I have a menu page which is supposed to be the main navigator.

Is there any way I can get this done?

Comment: InheritedWidget, probably

Comment: You can pass variables by making a data store that is either globally present in the runtime of your app or you could also use inherited widget

Comment: Create a static class and use it in any class !

Answer (score 0):

**WIDGET A**

```
SharedPreferences store = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
double addedValue = inputValueA + inputValueB;
preferences.setDouble("valueToBeDisplayed",addedValue);
```

**WIDGET B**

```
SharedPreferences store = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
double valueToBeGraphed = preferences.getDouble("valueToBeDisplayed") ?? 0.0;
//addToGraph(valueToBeGraphed);
```

> SharedPreferences need to be added as dependencies.

This is a general idea how you can implement it in Persistent Application Storage.

However, a better way to share state across the widget tree is using some state-management techniques like Inherited Widget etc. but I would personally use **Provider** library as it feel simple and convenient.

Comment: Shared preferences should be provided very small and restricted memory. Not a good idea in general.

Comment: @VidorVistrom yes I am aware of that so I have also suggested using state management techniques for the general use-case of the problem.

But also usually web developers who come into reactive application development from using JS or JQuery have very little idea about state-management.
I too when starting learnt it using application-setting for data sharing then grasped the concept of state-management.